# Optimizing query, join of many tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table where i need to do a join on a lot of different tables. The data set is 140 000 records long.

An example looks like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e.designation
                         , e.remark
                         , e.moment
                         , e.rpm
                         , e.cycleK
                         , c.type
                         , d.description
                         , a.PAnr
                         , b.family
                         , b.articlenrKronhjul
                         , b.ratio
                         , a.oiltype
                         , a.oiltemp
                         , a.createdBy
                         , a.createdDate
                      FROM testdata_test a
                         , testdata_gear b
                         , testdata_damcategory c
                         , testdata_damage d
                         , testdata_result e
                     WHERE a.id = e.test_id 
                       AND e.id = d.result_id 
                       AND a.id = b.test_id 
                       AND c.id = d.category_id
                     ORDER 
                        BY designation asc
                     LIMIT 0, 10
```

It averages out on about 1 second, how can I speed this up?
I have been trying to add some indexes on some columns although without much improvement.

Anyone have any tips?

Edit:

Here is my query plan in regular and JSON format:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                     | key                      | key_len | ref            | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | PRIMARY                                           | NULL                     | NULL    | NULL           | 10617 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort      |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | TestData_gear_2e06cda4                            | TestData_gear_2e06cda4   | 5       | webappdev.a.id |     1 | NULL                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref  | PRIMARY,TestData_result_2e06cda4                  | TestData_result_2e06cda4 | 4       | webappdev.a.id |     5 | NULL                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ref  | TestData_damage_b583a629,TestData_damage_57f06544 | TestData_damage_57f06544 | 4       | webappdev.e.id |     1 | NULL                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL  | PRIMARY                                           | NULL                     | NULL    | NULL           |     4 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

| {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "a",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY"
            ],
            "rows": 10617,
            "filtered": 100,
            "attached_condition": "(`webappdev`.`a`.`id` is not null)"
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "b",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "TestData_gear_2e06cda4"
            ],
            "key": "TestData_gear_2e06cda4",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "test_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "5",
            "ref": [
              "webappdev.a.id"
            ],
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "e",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY",
              "TestData_result_2e06cda4"
            ],
            "key": "TestData_result_2e06cda4",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "test_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "4",
            "ref": [
              "webappdev.a.id"
            ],
            "rows": 5,
            "filtered": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "d",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "TestData_damage_b583a629",
              "TestData_damage_57f06544"
            ],
            "key": "TestData_damage_57f06544",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "result_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "4",
            "ref": [
              "webappdev.e.id"
            ],
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "c",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY"
            ],
            "rows": 4,
            "filtered": 75,
            "using_join_buffer": "Block Nested Loop",
            "attached_condition": "(`webappdev`.`c`.`id` = `webappdev`.`d`.`cate
gory_id`)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
} |
```

Here are my CREATE TABLES and counts for the tables

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE testdata_test;
| testdata_test | CREATE TABLE `testdata_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PAnr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `projectAcc` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reportnr` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oiltype` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oiltemp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `headline1` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `headline2` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testDescription` longtext,
  `TestName` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBy` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `createdDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `test_index_testdescription` (`testDescription`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14172 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
    mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM testdata_test;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    14161 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)





mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE testdata_gear;
| testdata_gear | CREATE TABLE `testdata_gear` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `family` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `articlenrKronhjul` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revisionK` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `articlenrPinjong` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revisionP` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ratio` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `geardata` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remark` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_id` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `TestData_gear_2e06cda4` (`test_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `TestData_gear_test_id_325c2ab6_fk_TestData_test_id` FOREIGN KEY (`
test_id`) REFERENCES `testdata_test` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14167 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM testdata_gear;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    14157 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

  | testdata_result | CREATE TABLE `testdata_result` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `designation` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `remark` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `moment` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `rpm` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cycleK` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `test_id_result_index` (`test_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `result_designation_index` (`designation`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `TestData_result_test_id_5ed0cbc8_fk_TestData_test_id` FOREIGN KEY
(`test_id`) REFERENCES `testdata_test` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=141382 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM testdata_result;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   141323 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE testdata_damage;
| testdata_damage | CREATE TABLE `testdata_damage` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `part` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11),
  `result_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `TestData_damage_b583a629` (`category_id`),
  KEY `TestData_damage_57f06544` (`result_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `damage_index_description` (`description`),
  CONSTRAINT `TestData_damage_category_id_215346e4_fk_TestData_damcategory_id` F
OREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `testdata_damcategory` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `TestData_damage_result_id_2fb199b2_fk_TestData_result_id` FOREIGN
KEY (`result_id`) REFERENCES `testdata_result` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=141341 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM testdata_damage;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   141291 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE testdata_damcategory;
| testdata_damcategory | CREATE TABLE `testdata_damcategory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM testdata_damcategory;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        5 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT e.designation
...
) AS x;

+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   141298 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.40 sec)¨
```

EDIT:
Explain with the index for designation added

```
| {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "a",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY"
            ],
            "rows": 10617,
            "filtered": 100,
            "attached_condition": "(`webappdev`.`a`.`id` is not null)"
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "b",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "TestData_gear_2e06cda4",
              "test_id_gear_index"
            ],
            "key": "TestData_gear_2e06cda4",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "test_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "5",
            "ref": [
              "webappdev.a.id"
            ],
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "e",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY",
              "test_id_result_index"
            ],
            "key": "test_id_result_index",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "test_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "4",
            "ref": [
              "webappdev.a.id"
            ],
            "rows": 4,
            "filtered": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "d",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "TestData_damage_b583a629",
              "TestData_damage_57f06544",
              "result_id_damage_index"
            ],
            "key": "TestData_damage_57f06544",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "result_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "4",
            "ref": [
              "webappdev.e.id"
            ],
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "c",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY"
            ],
            "rows": 4,
            "filtered": 75,
            "using_join_buffer": "Block Nested Loop",
            "attached_condition": "(`webappdev`.`c`.`id` = `webappdev`.`d`.`cate
gory_id`)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
} |
```

FINAL UPDATE:
Here is the query that finally did the trick and brought down the query time to below 0.1s for me.

```
SELECT e.designation
    , e.remark
    , e.moment
    , e.rpm
    , e.cycleK
    , c.type
    , d.description
    , a.PAnr
    , b.family
    , b.articlenrKronhjul
    , b.ratio
    , a.oiltype
    , a.oiltemp
    , a.createdBy
    , a.createdDate
FROM (
     SELECT e.id, e.designation, e.remark, e.moment, e.rpm, e.cycleK, e.test_id
         FROM testdata_result e
         ORDER BY moment asc
         LIMIT 10
      )e
JOIN testdata_damage AS d  ON d.result_id = e.id
JOIN testdata_test AS a ON a.id = e.test_id
JOIN testdata_gear AS b ON a.id = b.test_id
JOIN testdata_damcategory as c ON c.id = d.category_id;
```

Comment: Can you post the query plan?

Comment: Comma joins were in effect deprecated in 1995. Join us.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning.

Comment: As I commented below I'll be away until Monday but I'll post the tables and stuff then.

Comment: I've edited the question now with the tables and row counts @AndyLester

Comment: Anyone got any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second glance, I think `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is preventing any attempt to speed up the query.  That requires that all the `JOINs` be fully done.  In my previous answer I was hopping to short circuit the evaluation after 10 rows.  That is not possible.

So, the "right" solution involved changing the application to do something about the count.

- Get rid of it (and convince the users that they don't really need it);
- Cache it somewhere (nightly?);
- Approximate it

If, after removing `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, you still have trouble optimizing, then do this:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM (
        SELECT e.id, e.remark, e.moment, e.rpm, e.cycleK
            FROM result
            ORDER BY designation  -- check that there is a plain INDEX on this
            LIMIT 10
         ) ON e
    JOIN damage AS d  ON d.result_id = e.id  -- check for INDEX(result_id)
    JOIN ... (the rest of the tables other than `e`)
    ORDER BY designation  -- yes, this redundancy is necessary
```

This coding 'trick' is to move the `LIMIT` (or `GROUP BY`) into a subquery to decrease the number of rows to work with while doing the `JOINs`.  This is instead of `JOINing` lots of rows, then tossing most of them.

Comment: Yes this worked for me! I had to do the subquery and then i got my query time down to below 0.1 seconds. There were some syntax errors with your example so I'm going to update my question with the query that worked. Thank you so much for your help and patience with me.

Comment: @RickJames, I know this one is kind of old, but I ran into it and wondered if the suggested coding trick won't potentially change the results of the original query? If the ORDER BY and LIMIT will be executed before the joins (as a subquery), wouldn't that return potentially 10 different results than if the joins would have happened before (as some rows might not have a match in the other tables)?

Comment: @TomShir - That's a reasonable question.  I am _assuming_ that there is _exactly one_ row in each of the other tables for each of the 10 rows.  If this is wrong, then my query will deliver more than 10 or fewer than 10 rows, thereby violating the intent.  Meanwhile, I added a necessary `ORDER BY` for the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(designation)
```

might help some.

How many rows do you get without the `LIMIT 10`?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table so we can discuss further.

**Edit**

Never mind.  A resultset of 141K rows, including a `LONGTEXT` will take time.  You are lucky it takes only a second or so.  That a lot of stuff to shovel around.  Disks go only so fast; networks go only so fast.  It is not the query or the indexes that are causing it to be "slow"; it is the request.

What can you do with 141K rows?  Surely you do not display all of them to the user.  If you are munching on them in some way, surely that takes second(s), meaning that the query is only a part of the total time.

I suggested an index in order to avoid doing the filesort -- but I did not notice that it was `LONGTEXT`, thereby invalidating using a regular index.  A `FULLTEXT` index has no ordering.  Bottom line: my `INDEX(designation)` was useless.

There is essentially no way to speed up the query *as it stands*.  If you need to fetch 10 rows at a time, there may be techniques (not involving `OFFSET`) to make it work better.

Comment: Since it's the weekend I'm going to be away from my computer until Monday but I'll post the tables then. I get around 130 000 results without the limit 10. Or did you mean the Explain without limit 10?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` does not do a good job of taking into consideration any `LIMIT`.  I meant run the query without the `LIMIT`.  Suggest `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS x;` -- This will get just the count.  The subquery is your `SELECT` without the `LIMIT`.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` says `a` has about 10K rows, but the entire resultset (without the `LIMIT`) could be several times that due to all the `JOINs`.

Comment: Edited the question now with my CREATE TABLEs and with the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS x;`
@RickJames

Comment: Added index on designation and that only sped it up by 0,04 seconds

Comment: Hmm... strange.  It looks like `INDEX(designation)` should short circuit much of the JOIN work.  Please provide the `EXPLAIN` when you have that index.  I would expect `testdata_result e` to be the first table in the `EXPLAIN`.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` if your version allows such.

Comment: Unrelated comment:  `PRIMARY KEY(id), KEY(id)` is redundant since a `PRIMARY KEY` is a `KEY`.  That is, the `KEY(id)` can be `DROPped` from most (all?) of your tables.  (The change won't impact the question in hand.)

Comment: I've updated my create tables and added the query plan as JSON format. I also removed all the automated INDEXes that django gave me before and now only have one on designation in testdata_result. The query time is roughly the same as before just over 1 second both with and without index on designation @RickJames

Comment: Are each of these indexed?  `a.id`, `b.test_id`, `d.result_id`, and `c.id`?  (That's in addition to `e.designation`.)  I am trying to get it to start with `e` and use the index for `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Well the a.id and c.id are PRIMARY KEYs so if I understood your previous comments they are indexed. I don't think the b.test_id and d.result_id are indexed. Since the database is generated from django models I am not sure if it automatically adds index to all foreign keys. I will try to add indexes to those. @RickJames

Comment: After adding the Indexes mentioned above I still get a query time of 1 second. @RickJames So I guess they had the indexes from the beginning.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables; perhaps there is something subtle I have not yet spotted.

Comment: The `SHOW CREATE TABLES`s in the question are updated with the most recent version of the tables @RickJames

Comment: By the way thank you for still trying to help me figure this out

Comment: a,b,c,d have the necessary indexes, but still missing `testdata_result` - `INDEX(designation)`

Comment: Added index, still results around 1 second

Comment: Can we see the `EXPLAIN` now that that index has been added.

Comment: I have added the explain with the index now